# ExtJs grid does not get resized when resizing the browser window.

Tags: gridview, extjs4

I have created a "html" page which contains the following code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>test Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.require(['*']);

            Ext.onReady(function() {


                Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
                    layout: {
                        type: 'border'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        region: 'center',
                        layout: 'border',
                        border: false,
                        items: [{
                            region: 'center',
                            title: 'Center',
                            contentEl: 'DivMain'
                        }]
                    }]
                });

                var myData = [
                    ['3m Co', 71.72, 0.02, 0.03],
                    ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01, 0.42, 1.47],
                    ['Altria Group Inc', 83.81, 0.28],
                    ['AT&T Inc.', 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, ],
                    ['Boeing Co.', 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, ]
                ];

                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
                    fields: [{
                        name: 'company'
                    }, {
                        name: 'price',
                        type: 'float'
                    }, {
                        name: 'change',
                        type: 'float'
                    }, {
                        name: 'pctChange',
                        type: 'float'
                    }

                    ],
                    data: myData
                });
                var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                    store: store,
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Company',
                        flex: 1,
                        dataIndex: 'company'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Price',
                        flex: 1,
                        dataIndex: 'price'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Change',
                        flex: 1,
                        dataIndex: 'change'
                    }, {
                        text: '% Change',
                        flex: 1,
                        dataIndex: 'pctChange'
                    }],
                    height: 250,
                    width: '100%',
                    title: 'Array Grid',
                    renderTo: 'grid-example',
                    viewConfig: {
                        stripeRows: true
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        <div id="DivMain">
            <div id="grid-example"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when resizing the browser page, no horizontal scroll bar comes and the gridview is not resized, so that the data of the right hand side of the gridview is not shown.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why not add grid to viewport than 'grid renderTo div and contentEl'

Answer (score 0):

The ExtJs library has EventManager class. Class is responsible for register various events.
The class has method "onWindowResize", which trigered when browser resizes.
So you need to subscribe to this event . [See link for example](http://myextjs.blogspot.com/2011/11/resize-window-resize-grid.html)